# grouping by items in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
>>> with open('Book2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    inpreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in inpreader:
        print ','.join(row)

IdNo, skillsList
BAXA0000206_NEENA_TIWARI_0.htm,[u'Training', u'E-Learning', u'PowerPoint', u'Teaching', u'Accounting', u'Team Management', u'Team Building', u'Microsoft Excel', u'Microsoft Office', u'Financial Accounting', u'Microsoft Word', u'Customer Service']
BAXA0000227_ABDUR_RAZZAQUE_0.htm,[u'Telecommunications', u'Data Center', u'ISO 27001', u'Management', u'BS25999', u'Technology', u'Information Technology...', u'Certified PMP\xae', u'Certified BS25999 Lead...']
BAXA0000261_Priya _ Lobo_0.htm,[u'Market Research', u'Segmentation', u'Marketing Strategy', u'Consumer Behavior', u'Experience Working with...']
```

I want to find out the term frequency of each skill in skillsList.. How can I do it...

Thanks

Comment: Where is the frequency field ?

Comment: skillsList.  I want the term frequency of each skill. Something like, Training : 45, E-Learning : 50

Comment: How does the CSV file look like? (I suppose you are now showing the output of your code, not the input)

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = {}
for skill_list in lists:
    for skill in skill_list:
        counter[skill] = counter.get(skill, 0) + 1

print counter
```

Comment: I did this, did not work. Can u please correct where I am going wrong.  >>> with open('Book2.csv', 'rb') as f:
 inpreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
 for row in inpreader:
  Lists = ','.join(row)

  
>>> len(Lists)
1
>>> counter = {}
>>> for skill_list in Lists:
 for skill in skill_list:
  counter[skill] = counter.get(skill, 0) + 1

  
>>> print counter
{',': 1}

Comment: counter = {}
with open('Book2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    inpreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in inpreader:
        for skill in row[1]:
            counter[skill] = counter.get(skill, 0) + 1
        print ','.join(row)
        
print counter
[link](http://simonsagi.com/sites/stackoverflow/frequency.txt)